# Show that numbers of the form $x/y$ for all $y \in \mathbb{N}$ and $1\leq x < y$ is the set of all rational numbers between $0$ and $1$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Show that numbers of the form $x/y$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1\leq x < y$ and for all $y$ in the domain, is the set of all rational numbers between $0$ and $1$ (exclusive).

This *feels* quite obvious but I'm not sure of how to reason this out. I think we are to begin with considering the pairs $(x,y)$ and somehow create one-one correspondence with something and be done.

Comment: Whoever downvotes this is requested to state the cause. Thank you!

Comment: That all such number are rational is true by definition, and it's clear that they are between $0$ and $1$ also, so you just need to show that every rational in $(0,1)$ can be expressed in this form.  What is your difficulty?

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "for all $y$ in the domain"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to prove something obvious, you have to be very careful about stating your assumptions! Here, you forgot to state that $x$ also has to be in $\mathbb N$. As for the proof, that's easy:

- Suppose $1\le x < y$, with $x,y\in\mathbb N$. Then $x/y$ is rational, by definition; and $x\in(0,1)$
- Suppose $r\in(0,1)$ is rational. Then $r=x/y$ for some $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ with $y\ne 0$. We may suppose $y>0$; if not, replace $x$ with $-x$ and $y$ with $-y$. Now we must have $1\le x<y$.

Answer (score 0):

You have two sets:

- $A = \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$
- $B = \{x/y | x,y \in \mathbb{N}, x<y\}$

To show $A=B$, you must prove that $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$.

Assume $a \in A$. Can you prove $a \in B$? This implies $A \subseteq B$

Assume $b \in B$. Can you prove $b \in A$? This implies $B \subseteq A$